# PHP/MySQL - Calculating student grades average

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my mysql:

```
$avg_ = $db->prepare("SELECT AVG(grades.grade) as `avg` 
            FROM grades WHERE student_id = :student_id");
$avg_->execute(array(':student_id' => $xx));
$avg_r = $avg_->fetch();
$avg = substr($avg_r['avg'], 0, 4);
```

And, for example, now I have the following grades:
Math: 4, 2
English: 3, 5
German: 5, 5
Physic: 5, 5, 1, 1, 5
Sociology: 4, 5, 5
IT: 5, 5

It outputs: 4.06, but it should 4.16, because upper(avg(4, 2)) = 3, upper(avg(3, 5)) = 4...

Comment: Can you show us the table structure as it's hard to help with what you have posted so far?

Comment: @atallon I have table `grades`, and in it the following columns: `id`, `subject_id`, `student_id`, `grade`

Comment: 4.06 is correct - you have 65 total out of 16 grades 65/16 = 4.0625

Comment: @AR. But that is not what I want, look, I will explain again:
I have the following grades in Math: 4, 2, which is (4+2)/2 = 3.00  
English: 3, 5, which is (3+5)/2 = 4.00 | German: 10/2 = 5.00 | Physic: 5, 5, 1, 1, 5, which is (5+5+1+1+5)/5 = 3.40 | Sociology: (4+5+5)/3 = 4.66 | IT = 5.00 ------ Now I want rounded values of the following: 3.00 = 3, 4.00 = 4, 5.00 = 5, 3.40 = 3, 4.66 = 5, 5.00 = 5, and finally I want average like: (3+4+5+3+5+5)/6 = 4.16